# Polymorphic instance returning polymorphic instance

Tags: c++, polymorphism

The design that **classes are inherited from one parent and their polymorphic methods return also polymorphic instances** is bad design because of `dynamic_cast`?

The following is an example.

```
#include <iostream>
class Data{
public:
virtual void doSomething(){}
};
class DataB:public Data{};
class DataC:public Data{};

class ClassA{
public:
  virtual Data* func() = 0;
};

class ClassB:public ClassA{
public:
  DataB* func(){
    return new DataB();
  }
};

class ClassC:public ClassA{
public:
  DataC* func(){
    return new DataC();
  }
};

int main(){
  ClassA * obj = new ClassB();
  Data * data = obj->func();
  DataB* data_b = dynamic_cast<DataB*>(data);
  if(data_b){
    std::cout<<"This is DataB"<<std::endl;
  }else{
    DataC * data_c = dynamic_cast<DataC*>(data);
    if(data_c){
      std::cout<<"This is DataC"<<std::endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

To figure out from which the instance generated, `dynamic_cast` is needed.

But many people says `dynamic_cast` should not be necessary.

With that reason, is it wrong design?

Comment: Can you reduce your example to the minimal code which we need to understand your problem?! For me to much non logical stuff here. Base->DataA->DataB->DataC.

Comment: The whole point of *polymorphic design* is that the code should not need to know the exact type of the polymorphic objects. If it does need to know the exact type (it needs a cast) then that indicates poor design. However sometimes you can't avoid the cast.

Comment: What is your use case? For me it looks like an academic question only. Why someone need such a design? Getting data from an instance  and process that data outside the class which produces the data seems to be the first problem. Classes should handle their data them self. What you give us is very bad design! And having data classes and handler classes looks like bad c code.

Comment: Your example is way too abstract for me to comment on the design tbh.

Comment: *"To figure out from which the instance generated, dynamic_cast is needed."* - In good polymorphic design you should not have to care what instance was generated.

Comment: @Galik "If it does need to know the exact type (it needs a cast)  then that indicates poor design. " Why? How would you design an "event queue/dispatcher" which needs to dispatch events based on the type of the events (say, an enum if you hate RTTI) and `dynamic_cast` them to meet the method signature of the consumer? (yes, I noted your "sometimes you can't avoid the cast")

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi That's kind of abstract but perhaps you get the objects to dispatch themselves? In pure polymorphism the objects have all the decision making knowledge so **they** make these decisions because **they** know what type they are. But like I said *sometimes* you need the cast. But if you are casting in too many places (more then one) then maybe you're missing a trick or polymorphism is the wrong tool?

Comment: @Galik: "But like I said sometimes". Need the cast means to process the data somewhere outside. Why there is no processing function in that object itself. Can you point to an example where the cast is really needed?

Comment: @Galik " but perhaps you get the objects to dispatch themselves" Can't be. It's like saying "having the objects knowing how to persistent-ilize themselves is a good design". (it may appear good until you get into the issue of having different persistence formats). In the general case, dispatching may need tons of context (knowledge about environ) to work properly - why couple an essentially-"transport object"  (the polymorphic event) with the logic of dispatching and call this a good design?

Comment: @Klaus "Can you point to an example where the cast is really needed?" does the example "event/dispatching-by-event-type" qualifies?

Comment: @Klaus Again its difficult to talk in abstracts. What about when the author of the object is not privy to the details of how it will be processed? Then it may not be possible to encode that in the object itself. Not all parts of a system will necessarily lend them selves to polymorphic design. Those parts may need to differentiate the objects.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I have no idea about the specifics of the system you have in mind which is why I keep saying ts hard to talk in abstracts and why I keep saying sometimes casting is needed.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi: Instead of `switch(event->type)... case x: to_somewhere->Dispatch(event)` you can also make it: `event->Dispatch()` which results in `virtual Dispatch()... ` with `to_somewhere->Send()` But not the place here to start such discussion :-)

Comment: @Galik "publisher-subscriber pattern" and [message brokers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_broker)  ring a bell? But maybe Klaus is right and this is not the place to start such a discussion. (what irked me was the categorical bit in the " then that indicates poor design.". If that had been " then that *may* indicate poor design *and probably would warrant closer inspection*", then I would not have had any objections)

Comment: @Klaus "But not the place here to start such discussion" (mumble-mumble... `to_somewhere->Send()` send exactly what? Where's the payload parameter?) Ok, let's drop it.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I used the word "indicate" to avoid being *categorical* and then further qualified my statements by saying that sometimes a cast was necessary. But those areas of a system that use a cast are **not** following *polymorphic* design. But that's okay. Polymorphism can not solve evey problem or even every part of a problem. Not every part of a system should be polymorphic.

Comment: @Galik Ok. my bad. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

dynamic_cast will return NULL if  it's argument isn't convertible to required class. Issue with this method is that  if there is more than one level of inheritance, a dynamic_cast to intermediate child of base class  returns valid pointer as well.

The design is bad because from polymorphism ideology's POV it's better to implement extra functionality  for virtual methods already declared in base class. Another way is to implement some type identification method, overridden by children, you would still need dynamic_cast, but use it only for one try.

Answer (score 0):

In True/Pure Object Oriented Design "Design By Interface" is the key. That is, every where the Base class pointers should be used without knowing the underlying derived classes and things should work.

Your code show the well known "Design Pattern - Abstract Factory" which states that : Abstract Factory provides an interface for creating families of related or dependent objects without specifying their concrete class.

***To figure out from which the instance generated, dynamic_cast is needed.***
That depends upon the requirement in product/ systems. Over a period of time requirement are generated/change and it becomes difficult to maintain the Key "Design By Interface" and therefore one is forced to use `dynamic_cast`. Also, in the workflow, if you really want to use something (which is not polymorphic) in derived class then `dynamic_cast` will be required which does not actually say 'hey! your design is bad.'

***But many people says dynamic_cast should not be necessary.*** Again, while starting a new/fresh product/system, the design should be such that the need to know concrete objects is minimal or use of `dynamic_cast` are  almost nil.

***With that reason, is it wrong design?***
That depends upon the current phase of our product/system. If you are freshly doing design of product then you need to reconsider the design if `dynamic_cast` is used. If the product/system is old or has too much of legacy code then you might make use of `dynamic_cast` inorder to solve the problem in hand.

Answer (score -1):

Perfectly designed OOP program should not resort to using casting which is similar to hacking. I have changed your code snippet avoiding the dynamic casting. Avoid using DataB* and DataC* as the abstract base class Data* can handle it and the member functions in ClassB and ClassC will be more homogeneous.

```
#include <iostream>
class Data{
public:
virtual void doSomething(){}
};
class DataB:public Data{};
class DataC:public Data{};

class ClassA{
public:
  virtual Data* func() = 0;
};

class ClassB:public ClassA{
public:
  Data* func(){
    return (DataB*) (new DataB());
  }
};

class ClassC:public ClassA{
public:
  Data* func(){
    return (DataC*) (new DataC());
  }
};

int main(){
  ClassA * obj = new ClassB();
  Data * data = obj->func();
  Data* data_b = data;
  if(data_b){
    std::cout<<"This is DataB"<<std::endl;
  }else{
    Data * data_c = data;
    if(data_c){
      std::cout<<"This is DataC"<<std::endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: But this code does not work now. If you change `obj` to `ClassC` [it prints](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BVH6C8vyYDd2tpy1) "This is DataB" which is incorrect.

Comment: @ChrisDrew : That's because obj = new ClassB() and  which is predictable and nothing wrong . For other data, use obj1 = new ClassC() and data_c = obj1->func()